# Accessing strange directory in linux shell

Tags: linux, ssh, escaping, putty

I have found a directory while connecting to a linux ssh shell and i putty the name is ??? (I assume it to be so because of escape characters used for the name).

---

When I use the command `ls -b` I get 3 results, `\t\t\t\`    `A_File.txt`  `A_Directory` but with a simple ls, all I get is `A_File.txt` `A_Directory`

---

Upon further research I have discovered the characters escapes to be [Octal Escape Characters](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ls.htm) and when i type `cd [tab][tab][tab]` ([tab] = pressing tab) I get a new listing of files, `^I^I^I /` `A_Directory`

---

How would you view the escaped character directory in this type of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a literal tab. With Bash you could use

```sh
cd $'\t\t\t'
```

or

```sh
printf -v tab '\t'
cd "$tab$tab$tab"
```

Comment: there was an escape character I was missing, `\ ` at the end of `\t\t\t` so the real directory is `\t\t\t\ ` is `\s` for spaces? (it isn't) Thanks! it worked, all I had to do was add a space on the end

Comment: how would I achieve the same result in filezilla? do you by chance know?